# Is there any way to stop VMware server from shutting down a client due to inactivity?

Tags: vmware

How can I stop VMware server shutting down my VMware client?

I have tried using a little app called Caffeine, which simulates key presses, but this doesn't work.

I want some app that runs in the background that convinces the server that the client is still in use - any ideas?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "client"?  A VM?

Comment: yes, so if you're working in a VM instance and dont want the server to shut it down..

Comment: Are you sure it's the **server** that shutting the client down, and not the client going into standby/hibernate due to inactivity? By default, newly installed Windows will go into standby after x minutes, and VMWare will "pause" such client. So, please define better which clinet is shutting down, and if this is a real OS shutdown or just a "pause".

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the the client software you use to connect to VMware Server disconnecting or do you mean a virtual machine is being shut down?

VMware Server will not shut down a VM by default. If your VM is shutting down, something is triggering it.